# Squid 3 custom error message

Tags: squid, custom-errors, zentyal

I'm currently migrating a tiny Zentyal firewall from 2.2 to 3.0. Almost complete, but I can't figure out how to update the Squid 3 error page with some additional paragraphs.

So far I've figured out that I get an `ERR_ACCESS_DENIED` page.

Changing the `/usr/share/squid3/errors/LANGUAGE/ERR_ACCESS_DENIED` works but changing the template `/usr/share/squid3/errors/templates/ERR_ACCESS_DENIED` does not help. As squid has a lot of language subfolders I do not want to change them one by one... Is there a way to generate them?

(Most tutorials just change the English language text. But non-English browsers are getting a localized page so this is not an acceptable solution for me.)

On Zentyal 2.2 editing `/usr/share/zentyal/stubs/squid/template.html.mas` worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I found this thread trying to solve the exact same problem. What I ended up doing was providing templates for english and norwegian (the country this was used in) - all other languages was removed. I did this with the [error_directory directive](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/error_directory/).

This isn't really a solution to your challenge, but it covered my needs atleast :)